# edit first line of multiple files in place with a ruby one-liner

Tags: ruby

I can edit multiple files in place using the -p -i -e command line options:

```
ruby -pi -e 'sub(/a/,"b")' file*
```

How can I edit only the first line of each file?  This works for one file only:

```
ruby -pi -e 'sub(/^/,"New line goes at top\n") if $. == 1' file1
```

This does not work:

```
ruby -pi -e 'sub(/^/,"New line goes at top\n") if $. == 1' file*
```

The line-number variable, `$.`, is not reset for each file.

My solution is to check for `$FILENAME` changing and then keeping track of what `$.` was at that point. Is that it, or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work:

```
ruby -pi -e 'sub(/^/,"New line goes at top\n") if $FILENAME != $F;$F = $FILENAME' file*
```

Comment: oh, ok, thanks. I actually tried the same thing but with a local variable, which would get an 'undefined local variable' error